# Using non-Shimano link with Shimano chain?

Tags: chain, shimano, master-link

I know the official answer from Shimano is you can only use their quick link, but practically is it okay to use SRAM or KMC links?

Specifically, I have the Shimano HG-40 chain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general a SRAM or KMC link for an 8 or 9 speed chain will work fine with a similar Shimano 8 or 9 speed chain.

If you are dealing with a 10 speed chain I believe you will run into a compatibility problem as one brand is sightly narrower than the other (I can't remember which way and I only deal personally with 9 speed or lower).

I've used a SRAM power link on a Shimano HG-40 for a while now with no problems.

Comment: I'd go for it without worry, too.

Comment: Several hundred km in mountain conditions on a Shimano XTR, joined by a KMC 10-sp link. No problem so far.

Comment: KMC's faq at http://kmcchain.us/faqs/ says the following: IS KMC MISSING LINK COMPATIBLE WITH SHIMANO CHAIN, SRAM CHAIN, OR CAMPY CHAIN?  Yes, KMC constructs Missing Link I, II, 9, and 10 for 7.3mm, 7.1mm, 6.6mm, and 5.9mm respectively; all Missing Links are compatible with Sram, Shimano, and Campy equivalent chains.